# whether the function is uniformly continous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)=exp(-1/x^2)$ if $x>0$, otherwise $f(x)=0$.

And $g(x)=exp(-1/(1-x)^2)$ if $x<1$, otherwise $g(x)=0$.

Both functions are defined on real number. I want to know wheter $h(x)=f(x)/(f(x)+g(x))$ is uniformly continous on $R$.
I tried to show that by definition of uniformly continuous, but failed. (And I also tried weierstrass M-test)
How can I know whether $h(x)$ is uniformly continuous function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could calculate $h'(x)$ and see if $|h'(x)|<M$ for some constant $M>0$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.